# Can mongodb queries based on an equation?

Tags: sql, mongodb, database

When in MySQL, we can query through the statement to search the records match an equation condition like "select * from location where (x - 10) * (x - 10) + (y - 20) * (y - 20) < 100". However, in MongoDB, I don't know how to make a query equivalent the above SQL statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three different ways to do queries with math.

1. The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) has [arithmetic operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/) like $add, $mul or $divide, which can be used in a [$project](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to create computed fields. It also has comparison operators like $gt and $lt which can then be used in a following [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) step to filter based on a computed field.
2. The [$where](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) operator allows you to write full-fledged Javascript code which is executed for every document. The function needs to return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not that document should be machted.
3. [MapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) allows to write map- reduce- and finalize methods in Javascript which can perform any arithmetics you want.